# Why does my datastore not save data and not get error messages in output?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a game like find the markers and I tried making a datastore but it doesn't work.
I'm getting no errors in output.
Here is the script:

```
local DS = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DSS = DS:GetDataStore("A1")


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    wait()
    local plrkey = "id_"..plr.UserId
    
    local savevalue1 = plr.Balls["Cool Marker"]
    local savevalue2 = plr.Balls["Angry Ball"]
    local savevalue3 = plr.leaderstats["Balls Found"]
    
    local GetSave = DSS:GetAsync(plrkey)
    if GetSave then
        savevalue1.Value = GetSave[1]
        savevalue2.Value = GetSave[2]
        savevalue3.Value = GetSave[3]
    else 
        local NumbersForSaving = {savevalue1.Value, savevalue2.Value, savevalue3.Value}
        
        DSS:GetAsync(plrkey, NumbersForSaving)
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    local savevalue1 = plr.Balls["Cool Marker"]
    local savevalue2 = plr.Balls["Angry Ball"]
    local savevalue3 = plr.leaderstats["Balls Found"]
    local saveValues = {savevalue1.Value, savevalue2.Value, savevalue3.Value}
    DSS:GetAsync("id_"..plr.UserId, saveValues)
end)
```

I made the script expecting it to save data. The first test I did I got a few bugs and fixed them. On my second test I got no errors but my data wasn't saved. I even tried doing it on actual servers but still no luck.

Comment: You have a typo. When the player leaves, you need to use `DSS:SetAsync`

Comment: oh my god thank you so much you have no idea how long i spent trying to fix this.